# How to group a column in PySpark to a list?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

Suppose I have a dataframe:

```
product_id  customer
1 1
1 2
1 4
2 1
2 2
```

I want to group the above dataframe as:

```
product_id customers
1 [1,2,4]
2 [1,2]
```

How could I do that with PySpark?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f 
df.groupby("product_id").agg(f.collect_list("customer").alias("customers")).show()
```

(**edit note** - added import statement in the code)

Comment: Thanks, but what is ``f``?

Comment: Is it possible to do concatenation of rows?

Comment: @NikhilBaby can you elaborate your requirement? Maybe you should create a new question and paste the link over here.